# jQuery logical operator || (or) sintax error

Tags: jquery, logical-operators

I know this is a beginner's question, but I don't understand why the following syntax error occurs:

```
...
else if (artist1.toLowerCase() == "anister huls" && title1.toLowerCase() == "i remember yesterday") || (artist1.toLowerCase() == "belle" && title1.toLowerCase() == "rock the boat") { 
    var cover = "http://my_url/img/tag/same_image.jpg"; 
    }
...
```

Result:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '||'

Error occurs only with `||` operator.

This syntax would be correct in JavaScript, why doesn't it work in jQuery?

Comment: This is not at all related to jQuery. It's just JavaScript. jQuery is just a JavaScript framework, not a separate language. You don't even have jQuery code here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing some parenthesis. An `If` statement condition requires parenthesis around the entire condition check.

Change

```
else if (artist1.toLowerCase() == "anister huls" && title1.toLowerCase() == "i remember yesterday") || (artist1.toLowerCase() == "belle" && title1.toLowerCase() == "rock the boat") {
```

to

```
else if ((artist1.toLowerCase() == "anister huls" && title1.toLowerCase() == "i remember yesterday") || (artist1.toLowerCase() == "belle" && title1.toLowerCase() == "rock the boat")) {
```

Comment: You're welcome. Enjoy your coding journey! :)